# Ctrl+; does not work to "Move Window to Left Side of Screen" for Firefox

Tags: keyboard, split-view

I set a shortcut for **All Applications**,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to "Move Window to Left Side of Screen"

and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> to "Move Window to Right Side of Screen"

it works for **Safari**, but when I use it on **Firefox**, the cursor disappears, and the Window does not move.

Comment: Custom Shortcuts on macOS do not work for Firefox. Yes, it is very annoying. No, I do not believe they are actively working on a fix. You could still submit a bug report, though. The more attention this issue gets the more likely they are to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that Firefox has built-in shortcuts (i.e. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to take screenshots) that went into conflict with your custom shortcuts. I checked briefly on Google but didn't find any centralized built-in shortcuts settings page, maybe you'll have to dig in deeper.

Comment: I even attempted a few more combinations, but none of them worked, am using Chrome for the specific task as of now.

Comment: Maybe you could file a bug report at [Bugzilla of Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/home)? I believe the developers of Firefox can look deeper into this.

Comment: thanks for the link, have created an issue.